# Vertical & Horizontal align in a DIV

Tags: css, html, center, vertical-alignment

I've got a DIV with a BG image, and I want to center just 2 paragraphs both vertically and horizontally within that DIV.  Here's the code:

Code:

```css
#dark-table-carol {
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-image: url(http://scott.ewarena.com/blog/wp-content/themes/bootstrapstarter/carol-candy-carts-quote.jpg);
  height: 600px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  margin: auto;
  /*
  position: absolute;
  background-size:contain;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  right: 0;
  */
}
```

```html
<div id="dark-table-carol">
  <h3 id="dark-table-head-style" align="center">"It was like Scott reached into my head and saw exactly what I wanted to achieve. He brought my ideas to life very quickly!</h3>
  <p id="dark-table-paragraph" align="center">
    Carol Davies - Carol's Candy Carts
  </p>
</div>
```

I've tried a few things, obviously `vertical-align:middle;`, setting padding to 50% for top & bottom, but no luck.

Any advice would be great :) Thanks!
Scott

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following two styles to your image container.

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h3qh9pgu/

I've been looking the whole day for a better solution as the one I gave you will not work for me. Alas, I can't find answers. Hope this works for you. It worked in the fiddle.

Comment: This worked a treat. Thanks very much! I had tried vertical-align: middle; but didn't use the display: table-cell; option.  I'll have to read about its usage.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use `top` `bottom` `left` and `right` properties to center elements.
Change these values to check out how it behaves. And remember to add `margin` and `position` properties as shown below.

```css
#container{
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:dotted 1px #33aaff;
}

#child{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#ff55aa;
  
  position: absolute;
  margin:auto;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;   
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#dark-table-carol {
  display: table;
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-image: url(http://scott.ewarena.com/blog/wp-content/themes/bootstrapstarter/carol-candy-carts-quote.jpg);
  /*background-size:contain; */
  height: 600px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  margin: auto;
  /*position: absolute;
            top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;*/
}
.inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="dark-table-carol">
  <div class="inner">
    <h3 id="dark-table-head-style" align="center">"It was like Scott reached into my head and saw exactly what I wanted to achieve. He brought my ideas to life very quickly!</h3>
    <p id="dark-table-paragraph" align="center">
      Carol Davies - Carol's Candy Carts
    </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: For the parent div add display:table;
for the child div (in this case I gave it class inner) add display: table-cell; vertical-align:middle; margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;

Comment: Unfortunately for whatever reason this didn't work :(